HPolyhedron::MaximumVolumeInscribedEllipsoid fails with clarabel, claiming that PSD and Power Cones are not supported (Drake, C++)
I'm trying to approximate the volume of different HPolyhedrons using HPolyhedron::MaximumVolumeInscribedEllipsoid(), but (seemingly randomly) the clarabel solver will terminate with the following message.
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at external/crate__clarabel-0.6.0/src/solver/core/cones/psdtrianglecone.rs:292:9:
not implemented: Mixed PSD and Exponential/Power cones are not yet supported

At every iteration (this is for a variant of IRIS-NP), the same solver is used to find the maximum volume ellipsoid, and it works most of the time. I've managed to recreate the issue with an n=10 hpolyhedron, documented here.
I was under the impression that the ellipsoid "C" matrix is necessarily constrained to be Positive Semi-Definite, and that a unique Lorentz cone constraint was required for each linear constraint of the Polyhedron. Given the error (Mixed PSD and Exponential/Power cones are not yet supported), I'm unsure why the Clarabel solver even works otherwise.
Just in case, I additionally checked to see that the polyhedron was bounded (it was), non-empty (it was), and even that the chebychev center could be calculated (it could). The chebychev center for the provided HPolyhedron is finite
(3.51522 9.25613 3.36519 2.29893 2.57857   2.067  1.9737 3.20679 8.46754 5.83094). Finally, I tried removing redundant constraints (with 0 tolerance), and faced the same issue.
Is this an installation issue on my end? I installed Drake from source using cmake, (HEAD:
074d751b155244cb9cb4577bf111bb70afc71279 ). Is it possible that there is something erroneous with the HPolyhedron that I'm missing?
Thanks!
Edit: The error occurred when considering polytopes with small interiors. It no longer occurred when updating to the most recent versions of drake & clarabel.

The link to the reproduction does not work for me (on the n=10 HPoly). Is it a public repo?

@RussTedrake It was not, I just changed it. Apologies, that is embarrassing on my part.
